# Cannot implicitly convert type integer to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hope you can assist me with this issue. I searched earlier raised questions, but
    couldn't solve this with provided answers. 
    I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type integer to bool" in the where clause. 
    This while
    SchoolMasterID column in my database and the Id provided via the constructor both
    have the type integer.

```
public List<SchoolmasterIndexView> GetdSchoolMaster(EduDbContext db, int Id)
{
   var _schoolmaster = from n in db.SchoolMasters
   join c in db.Address on n.AddressID equals c.AddressID
   where **n.SchoolMasterID = Id**
   orderby n.SchoolMasterName
   select new SchoolmasterIndexView()
   {
      SchoolMasterID = n.SchoolMasterID,
      SchoolMasterName = n.SchoolMasterName,
      AddressID = c.AddressID,
      AddressLine1 = c.AddressLine1,
      AddressLine2 = c.AddressLine2,
      PostalCode = c.PostalCode,
      City = c.City
                   };
      return _schoolmaster.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use equality operator [==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) instead of assignment operator [=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) in `where` clause.

```
var _schoolmaster = from n in db.SchoolMasters
                    join c in db.Address on n.AddressID equals c.AddressID
                    where n.SchoolMasterID == Id //<--equality operator
                    orderby n.SchoolMasterName
                    ...
```

Consider next simple code:

```
from item in new []{1,2,3} //array of ints
where item = 2             //compilation error, because of assignment operator
select item;
```

compiler fires exactly the same error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`

This error appears, because assignment operator returns assigned value. For example:

```
int a;
var b = a = 2; //result of "a = 2" expression is 2 and then assigned to b 

Console.WriteLine(b); //prints 2. Two variables both have value 2
```

In Linq `where` clause expects `bool` but gets `int` type. That's why compiler complains, that it can't convert `int` to `bool`